# Trying to recreate a university database in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, entity-relationship, eer-model

I am trying to recreate a university database and have created the following EER model. I am still fairly new to MySQL and was just wondering if there should be any changes made to this model in order for it to work correctly. I am not overly sure how to design tables such as the "prerequisite" and "major" tables specifically.

Thanks for any advice

Here's the EER:

[image]

Comment: Your prerequisite should be an int (following your existing design pattern).  But in real life, isn't a prerequisite a course, hence a join back to itself?  Same comment about Major and its primary key.  Its core courses and electives should be another table to relate N:M of Majors:Courses

Comment: So do you mean that the core courses and electives in the "major" table should both be their own table and then join back to major?

Comment: I would remove the CoreCourses and Electives fields from the Major table.  Then create a new table with 3 fields: MajorName (foreign key to Major Table), CourseID (foreign key to COURSE table) and 'type' which would have the values: 'core' or 'elective'.  The primary key would be the composite of the MajorName and CourseID.